# Difference between Hamming Loss, Hamming Score, and Hamming Distance in multiclass multilabel classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm, k-means, multi-class, multilabel

I am trying to understand the mathematical difference between, Hamming distance, Hamming Loss and Hamming score. I am trying to perform two actions

1. Multiclass multi label classification using SVM
2. K Means clustering, and then calculate the above mentioned metrics by assigning majority class as predicted label in each cluster.